# Cron error while executing catalogrule_apply_all

Tags: cron, shopping-cart-price-rules, schedule

Wondering if anyone can help with this. Every few days, the catalogrule_apply_all cron task fails with the exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'.

Struggling to figure out what's going on. Our hosting company have done various checks on the database and found no issues but this still keeps happening and causing the shopping cart price rules to fail.

I'm also using AEO Scheduler;

```
Cron error while executing catalogrule_apply_all:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(571): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(590): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->_fillIndexData(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Website), 1472511600)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(126): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->_reindex(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Website), 1472511600)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(592): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->execute()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(545): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->_reindexCatalogRule(NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php(204): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->applyAllRules()
#12 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer->dailyCatalogUpdate(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(79): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#18 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(571): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(590): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->_fillIndexData(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Website), 1472511600)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php(126): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->_reindex(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Website), 1472511600)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(592): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh->execute()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(545): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->_reindexCatalogRule(NULL)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php(204): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->applyAllRules()
#11 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer->dailyCatalogUpdate(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(79): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/htdocs/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#17 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below posts it will same as yours

[Payment Deadlock issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/payment-deadlock-issue)

[SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89676/sqlstate40001-serialization-failure-1213-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-l)

[Price re-index causes DB deadlocks during checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260/price-re-index-causes-db-deadlocks-during-checkout)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040460/sqlstate40001-serialization-failure-1213-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-l